# When is the product $(1+1/3)\cdots(1+1/n)$ equal to an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

It looks like its never the case. Is that right?

Comment: Nope, the correct answer is B. Hint, try to write every factor as one fraction.

Answer (score 7):

HINT :

$$\left(1+\frac 13\right)\left(1+\frac 14\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\left(1+\frac 1n\right)=\frac 43\times \frac 54\times\cdots\times \frac{n}{n-1}\times\frac{n+1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\prod_{i=3}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)=\frac{1}{3}(n+1)$$

Comment: Why? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Write the inner part of the product as a common denominator and you will see the telescoping series.